# google inner join the spreadsheets

Tags: google-sheets

I've got two sheets, say "Products" and "Price", in both sheets there is a column "productid". I want to have a new column in sheet "Products", say "new_price" and get it from sheet "price".
Using SQL it would be no brainer:

`select a.col1, b.price as 'new_price' inner join products as a inner join price as b on a.productid = b.productid`

how to do it right in the google sheet?

Comment: you may have better luck on https://webapps.stackexchange.com/

Comment: You definitely need it scripted? or is a formula fine? if you want a dynamic formula, it's just a simple vlookup()

Answer (score 1):

The QUERY() function is modeled after SQL and is very powerful. However, not all SQL is supported such as JOINs. There are complicated formulas that can do that using various combinations of functions. I decided to write my own JOIN, I called it denormalize.

Here are some examples of usage:

```
=denormalize("Employees","Orders",1,3)
=denormalize("Employees","Orders",1,3,"full")
=QUERY(denormalize("Employees","Orders",1,3,"left"), "SELECT * ", FALSE)
```

You can get the complete custom function with lots of examples here:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1vziuF8gQcsOxTLEtlcU2cgTAYL1eIaaMTAoIrAS7mnE/edit#gid=0

Make a copy and check out the custom function in the script editor.